# Default Arguments vs. Overloading wrt. Name Lookup?

Tags: c++, overloading, default-arguments

In C++, given the alternatives:

```
void fun(int arg1, int arg2opt = 0);

// vs.

void fun(int arg1, int arg2);
void fun(int arg1) {
  fun(arg1, 0);
}
```

Are there any differences for user code wanting to use this function, that is, given any code base, which code constructs would break (at compile time or runtime) when I were to change the first definition into the second? (Overload resolution? Name lookup? *Assigning `fun` to a function pointer?* Usage in templates (`std::function`)? ...)

Or will these be the same semantically? ([here are some details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14285225/321013) that I know and that are not relevant for this question)

Comment: Depends on where your "user code" is. Ex: Consider what happens when the "user" is a polymorphic derivation and these are virtual members.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yeah, virtual functions obviously are a difficult beast with default arguments anyway.

Answer (score -1):

i think [this link](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/77-default-parameters/) is useful for start, but you named `template`, i have experienced in `template` , If your program is productive and don't have time to study to learn template, please stop, and learn templates in vacations.It doesn't have any quick ref and its erros a little differ with `OOD/P` , but if you have time, start it.